# Jquery UI Tabs remembers the position of current tab? Is there a way to disable this?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

JQuery UI Tabs remembers the current selected tab when we navigate from the current page and come back to the previous one (use anchor links for such page transfer) Is there any way I could disable the feature that makes the tabs to remember their current position? I checked the JQueryUI documentation for tabs but could not find where it sets the cookie to accomplish this. Any insight would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `tabs()` implementation certainly doesn't do it.  But are you sure the `cookie` option is `null`?  Otherwise it might be the `selected` option.   The [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs) mentions:

> **Cookie**:
>
> Store the latest selected tab in a
> cookie. The cookie is then used to
> determine the initially selected tab
> if the selected option is not defined
>
> **Selected**:
>
> Zero-based index of the tab to be
> selected on initialization. To set all
> tabs to unselected pass -1 as value.

Comment: you are right. One of the developers here had set a cookie. Thanks :-)